# How to send elasticsearch multi search request in Postman?

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I'm trying to send elasticserach multi search request via postman as below:

```
POST - http://localhost:9200/_msearch
content-type : x-www-form-urlencoded
body:
{"index":"accounts"}
{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"owner.first_name":"Creeple"}}]}}}
```

However, I'm getting following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Note that if I perform same request via my play code, results are succesfully fetched.

```
WS.url("localhost:9200/_msearch").withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(query)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but msearch is GET and not POST

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Three things are important here:

1. When inserting body, select **raw** radiobutton and **Text** (or JSON) from dropdown.
2. Add header: **Content-type: application/x-ndjson**
3. Most important: put **new line** after the last line of your query

**Body:**
[image]

**Header:**

[image]

**Curl version:**

```
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:9200/_msearch \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-ndjson' \
  -d '{"index":"script","type":"test"}
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
'
```

Comment: Thank you Joanna. I miss the part to set `content-type` to `application/x-ndjson`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! That last empty line on the bottom of the body is totally crucial. :-)

Comment: @Mikhail, please check official docs about [Request Body Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#search-request-body), especially this statement: *Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body. Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well.* Personally, when I send request with message body, I prefer to use POST.

Comment: Am I the only one, where application/x-ndjson does not work, but application/json ?

Comment: Something I was missing is that json should be squashed into one line. Don't know if this is stupid, but I certainly pulled my hair out because of the issue with json being properly formatted. I was receiving `Unexpected end-of-input` errors

Answer (score 5):

You can also make your request body be json format and change your Content-Type be application/json, please take a look as below

[image: Header with Content-Type]

[image: Your search request with json type]

[image: Response data]

Comment: The question was about Elasticsearch multi-search (_msearch), not _search. The most upvoted answer showing an example with _msearch and application/x-ndjson is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have found error for "Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [null]" when I use _msearch API in elasticsearch.

[Response of this api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAPvw.png)

[Request parameters and url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wxWr.png)

Comment: Please include the code here instead of the screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have use this CURL and it's working fine in my case

```html
curl --location 'localhost:9200/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "Text Here"
        }
    }
}'
```