# How to add filters to a request body with Postman and ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I want to extract my datas from my database with Postman. I need to access only objects which job=true like that :

```
  "hits": {
    "total": 25,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "realIndex",
            "_type": "superType",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "name": "mike",
                "job": true,
              }
```

Can I tanslate in Postman a body like that?

```
    body: JSON.stringify({
    query: {
      bool: {
        filter: [{ term: { job: true } }],
      },
    },
    size: 20,
  }),
```

Comment: i thinck you will have your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437217/how-to-send-elasticsearch-multi-search-request-in-postman

Comment: thanks but it didn't work :( What I tried : {"query":{"job":true}}   What I got:  "[job] query malformed, no start_object after query name"

Comment: You need to use the exact same query you have above, i.e. `{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{ "term": { "job": true } }]}},"size": 20}`

Comment: Thanks!!! it works!